# How can I enable usb debugging on a broken phone?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, broken-screen

My android mobile is accidentally broken. And the usb debugging is set to off. If I can enable it I could use it through visor in PC. But can't do it now. :( I don't have OTG supported too. My android version is **7.0 Nougat**. The manufacturer is **Symphony LiteTel**. Model: **Symphony LiteTel - LT4502** Is there any way? :(

Comment: The Android version is important, therefore thanks for including this info. However every Android device can be seen as unique, therefore you should additionally name the manufacturer and the exact model name of your device. Otherwise the answer is just "may be".

Comment: @Robert, I've added those information. Could you please check?

Comment: I thought may be your device has an MTP chip which allows to flash a custom firmware with pre-enabled adb. But your phone seems to be very special not even find some detailed tech specs. Hence this won't work - sorry.

Comment: :sob: @Robert thank you.

Comment: Related: [Can I enable USB debugging using adb?](/q/120394/16575) // [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](/q/12834/16575) // [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](/q/159551/16575) and probably more in the resp. "related" sections, as this is a question coming up frequently.

Answer (score 1):

**you can't do much because device has locked bootloader**

well. so spoken, you can't do much wrong and can try something stupid ;) basically `adb` can be enabled by modifying `boot` or `system` partition. but locked bootloader means no modifications allowed.

some older devices have no protection for flashing modified partitions, only `avb/dm-verity` will deny boot in such case.

**however, Magisk is able to by-pass dm-verity** in some cases. most likely you will **brick** your device with this method, but give it a try (you can repair it by restoring official partitions)

- download latest [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads)
- get a flash tool for your device. for Spreadtrum/Unisoc chipset it's [SPD Upgrade Tool](https://androidmtk.com/flash-pac-stock-rom-android-smartphone) (make sure you download latest version)
- install Spreadtrum USB drivers
- download [stock ROM](https://gsmflashrom.com/litetel-lt4502-spreadtrum-firmware-flash-file) according to your current android version / build number (you can check from fastboot)

  ```
  fastboot devices
  fastboot getvar all
  ```
- in `UpgradeDownload.ini` (SPD_Upgrade_Tool) change the following flags

  ```
  Repartition = 0
  ShowOtherPage = 1
  CanEdit = 1
  CanSelect = 1
  ```
- [extract](https://androidmtk.com/extract-spreadtrum-pac-file) the stock ROM and find the `boot.img` (you will patch) and the `userdata.img` (you must delete) in **SPD ImageFiles/_DownloadFiles**

---

**1. Magisk root + enable usb-debugging + by-pass dm-verity**

- unpack the `boot.img` with any ramdisk tool
  (i recommend [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-android-image-kitchen-unpack-repack-kernel-ramdisk-win-android-linux-mac.2073775) **unpackimg.bat**)
- modify `default.prop` to enable adb
  (use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) for correct line ending **LF**)

  ```
  ro.secure=0
  ro.adb.secure=0
  ro.debuggable=1
  persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
  ```
- repack ramdisk/kernel and copy `image-new.img` to any android device (android 7.0 recommended)
- install [Magisk Manager](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD) and patch the image file with settings *"keep AVB/dm-verity"* and *"keep force encryption"*
- goto settings - about device - tap build number 7x (seven) times and enable usb-debugging in developer options
- open `cmd.exe`, navigate to **platform-tools** folder and copy `magisk_patched.img` back to PC

  ```
  adb devices
  adb pull /sdcard/Download/magisk_patched.img
  ```

---

**2. now comes the tricky part. you must flash that file to your broken device (boot partition). that is untested and may fail**

- open SPD Upgrade Tool - Settings - Main Page. uncheck all entries that do not apply to boot partition
- especially make sure all entries related to *"Erase"* or *"UserData"* are removed. you only want to flash boot (not to confuse with uboot)
- select `magisk_patched.img` from **platform-tools** folder and replace the original `boot.img` in the proper entry
- Power off your device. connect your device. start the flashing process

[image: SPD_Upgrade_Tool.png]

---

**finally, reboot your device and check adb connection**

```
adb devices
scrcpy
```

if no adb connection that means the bootloader does not allow modified partitions and your device is bricked now

unbrick by flashing the **original** `boot.img` (see step 2)

**make sure never flash userdata you will lose all data**

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc

Comment: thank you so much for your contribution. I don't know if I could do this or not. But I'll try.

Comment: can confirm this method works 100% for Lenovo Tab 7 Essential (TB-7304F) and Cubot King Kong B-1 (X511) both with MTK SP Flash Tool