# How to disable kiosk mode or install new firmware on Android tablet running MLS/MAIC?

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, device-firmware, kiosk-mode

I am new to the Android programming world. I own an iQR70 device from MLS that is using -if I read well- the kiosk mode for its own application called MAIC (something like Amazon's Alexa, a virtual assistant).

[image]

The real pain with this device is that the application is buggy, does not get any updates, and overall does not work properly.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any way to disable the kiosk mode and work with it as a normal tablet? Or desperately,
2. Can I install compatible firmware? I don't care for the data inside.

---

I tried to install a stock firmware "Version: MLS iQR70 – 7.0_MT8167_V1.0_20180111-B1" from `https://firmware247.com/mls-iqr70-firmware/` using "Format all + Download" using MediaTek SP Flash Tool v5.2052.00 and now it does not power up. It doesn't even connect anymore with the SP Flash Tool.

[image]

Is the device completely dead? Is there any way to revive it? I have two of them, can I download/upload the firmware from the good one to the bad one?

Comment: unfortunately "format all + download" will erase secro persist and other important partitions. but the issue is probably flashed wrong preloader which bricked it completely (not sure about, preloader is for iqr-70 and should still work). disconnect battery and try again

Comment: @alecxs, so there is no chance to revive it anyway?

Comment: there is meta mode if you can figure out kcol0 test point https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-11802.html

Comment: @alecxs thank you, I will give it a try. Can you tell me please if I can quit/exit from the "kiosk mode" of the virtual assistant that comes with this tablet? In the other one I own, I have no access to anything but the virtual assistant. I can get in ADB mode but the device is not listed and I can use the fast mode which OEM unlock is not allowed. What are my options?

Comment: @alecxs This device does not have a battery at all but I formated also the preloader.... which as far as I understand is the connection with the hardware itself. The problem where is that SP Flash tool can not see the device anymore!!!

Comment: regarding adb: you can try to flash modified boot.img if it is signed AVBv1. check with AIK it will tell you during unpack. [instructions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232319)

Comment: "format all + download" only erased EMMC_USER (not preloader EMMC_BOOT). if device does not have battery disconnect power supply, preloader works without any power source

Comment: @alecxs I already did, but I get no response using SP FLASH. I think its totally dead!!. I will try the hardware solution. Regarding adb, you said to flash the modified boot.img. It seems that the firmware I downloaded it was incorrect for this device. So can I download the original boot.img to my HD and modify it someway?

Comment: do a full read back of the working device https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283

Comment: @alecxs ok I will try. The "bad" one using ONLY the USB cable does not respond to "ReadBack" command using SP Flash, which means only hardware intervention, am I right?

Comment: not sure, depends on what you mean with "respond". order is important. 1.) start read back 2.) connect usb cable. VCOM preloader drivers must pop up for ~1 second in windows device manager each time you connect

Comment: That's the correct order I followed, I tested also the good one and it worked immediately. The bad one does not respond to anything I tried so far.

Comment: maybe there is a battery inside you don't know?

Comment: @alecxs A small internal batter like CMOS for time/date? Yes, maybe but its a compact device that I didn't open as you can see in the attached photo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to see whether there is a code or secret tap on the Android device to see whether there is a chance of entering the back end. There must be a way, or else it would be difficult.

I found [an article](https://support.glorystartouch.com/portal/en/kb/articles/firmware-update-to-revert-to-android-default-launcher) that teaches how to revert back to the original firmware - but I guess it needs someone to send you the firmware in order to have access to it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/245846)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to escape from the MLS default app and use this device as a tablet. The process is easy and can be done in a couple of minutes:

1. While you set up the device, you are asked to connect to WiFi. When entering the password, a keyboard pops up. Long press on the spacebar and press "Voice".
2. Then a Voice prompt pops up with a settings gear on the left, click this and a new pop-up will appear.
3. On the top-right side, click Help & Feedback and Browser will open.
4. If you previously connected to WiFi, now you have a fully working browser (you don't need to be connected to the internet). In the browser's top-right corner, click the 3 dots and tap on "Share page".
5. A pop-up will appear with two options.
6. Long press on the Bluetooth icon and go to Bluetooth settings.
7. From there, if you swipe from the left, the setting navigation bar will appear.
8. Now you can unlock ADB debugging, etc.

Notes:

- MLS MAIC 3D app is being used as a default launcher, so you need to sideload another launcher e.g. Discreet Launcher, and use that as the default app.
- Make sure to disable Bot Tester, MLS Updater, Video Calls, and all other MLS-related apps.
- Some things are broken e.g. downloading from the default browser crashes (use Bluetooth, USB sideloading, or another browser)
- Recent button is disabled
- Notification bar is disabled
- There aren't any Google services - so no Play Store. I personally use F-Droid.

Congrats now you have a fully working Android tablet :)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it with my working device and I will let you know :-)