# How to unlock the bootloader of Safaricom Neon Ray Pro?

Tags: bootloader-lock

I have a Safaricom Neon Ray Pro, a carrier-based Android phone managed by an operator called SAFARICOM, a Kenyan network carrier. I want to unlock the bootloader, but as far as my device is carrier-based, they have locked that.

They had previous models in which one could unlock the bootloader where you can gain root access, flash custom ROMs, etc., but this one you cannot.  Even through ADB commands, my phone's bootloader cannot be unlocked. I wonder if I can bypass this.

[image]

Here are its details. I hope they help, it's not a common device.

[image]

Comment: if you don't care to brick that device you could try to flash magisk_patched.img from SPD Flash Tool on locked bootloader, maybe it works https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232319